# Multibinding seeking for a missing ancestor source error : simple tip?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

Let's say I have an UserControl like this :

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="SandBox.IconUC" 
    xmlns:sb="clr-namespace:SandBox" 
    x:Name="Icon_Control" ...>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <sb:IconActualScalingConverter x:Key="IconActualScaling_Converter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- ... -->
        <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IconActualScaling_Converter}">
                <Binding Path="BaseSize" ElementName="Icon_Control" />
                <Binding 
                    Path="ScalingOverride" 
                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=sb:ContainerUC}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

Obviously, I want to scale its **content** based on a dependency property of its own called **`BaseSize`**, **and a dependency property of a container UserControl somewhere in the path through this IconUC ancestors of type `ContainerUC`**.

This works very well when I set the IconUC as a decendant of one ContainerUC.

Unfortunately, when I put the Icon in another control, like a StackPanel, that has NO ContainerUC as ancestor, **I get the following warning** :

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 :
> **Cannot find source for binding** with reference
> 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='**SandBox.ContainerUC**', AncestorLevel='1''.
> BindingExpression:Path=**ScalingOverride**; DataItem=null;
> target element is 'ScaleTransform' (HashCode=51921052);
> target property is 'ScaleX' (type 'Double')

And that's normal.

### How to simply prevent that warning, like ignoring the Binding if resolving the path to the source failed ?

What I would like **is NOT a workaround** :

1. Using DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached on ContainerUC, and getting a default Metadata value in IconUC if no Ancestor was found. I know this is a good workaround.
2. Using (heavy) code behind to retrieve the desired Ancestor, or using a default value instead. This also works, and I don't even need a Converter for that.
3. Putting the StackPanel inside a ContainerUC. The StackPanel is there to test the Icons Sizes. Anyway, the Icons are in fact much more complex objects that would land in multiple type of containers, not just this ContainerUC.

What I would like **is just to learn whether it exists one way** to avoid errors even if the desired ancestor is missing in MultiBindings.

Tried **`FallbackValue="1.0"`** in Binding. Still getting the warning.
Tried **`TargetNullValue="1.0"`**. Still getting the warning.
Tried **`UpdateSourceExceptionFilter="SomeMethod"`**. Still getting the warning.
Tried **`NotifyOnValidationError="False"`**. Still getting the warning.

If the answer is ***No, your IconUC UserControl is doomed to be a descendant of ContainerUC*** in this case, then I'll be fine with that. :)

---

This is the simplified version of the converter. But I highly doubt the answer (if any) would land here : the warning is thrown well before the Converter handles the datas.

```
public class IconActualScalingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double definedScaling = (double)values[0];
        double scalingFactor = 1.0;

        if (values.Length > 1)
        {
            if (values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                scalingFactor = (double)values[1];
            }
        }
        return definedScaling * scalingFactor;
    }
    
    public object[] ConvertBack(...)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's just a warning in the debug window of Visual Studio. It doesn't affect anything, it's just an information for you. The binding will not be set in that case. What's the point in removing this warning message?

Comment: Ah!? Are you sure I can leave that warning there and go on ? I assumed _"warning = something wrong in your code ..!"_ that's why I'm looking for the steps to fix this exact specific warning. Yeah, the Binding is not set, that's why I have DependencyProperty.UnsetValue in the converter, but looks hacky to me. I just hoped something I missed could be done in the xaml MultiBinding. But if it's the way to go..

Comment: A data binding warning is just a diagnostic message. So, if you know that a missing binding source is okay, then just ignore the warning. It might help you to find out data binding problems, e. g. if you **have to** resolve all the bindings.

Comment: okay :) Thanks. The ScalingOverride Binding is only required for displaying purposes within the ancestor scope; I actually don't have to resolve this Binding if the ancestor is not there. I'll probably use the "wpf inheritable property" at a later time as a workaround (sorry, I'm stubborn I know, but those warnings somewhat bugs me :P )